# Fold left to create a immutable list

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a list of string and then concatenate them using `mkstring`

```
List("a", "b1")
    .foldLeft(ListBuffer.empty[String]) { (a, l) =>
    {
      if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(l))
        a += "abc" +l
      else a
    }
    }
    .mkString(";")
```

Output

`abca;abcb1`

I want to used a mutable list .
Solution tried

```
List("a", "b1").
foldLeft(List[String]())((b,a) => b:+"abc"+a).mkString(";")
```

I can perform the empty check.Can we refactor it to better to get rid of if and else

```
   List("a", "b1","","c2").
   foldLeft(List[String]())((b,a) =>
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(a))
     b:+"abc"+a
    else b
).mkString(";")
```

Can anyone help

Comment: Why you cannot perform the check?, which error message did you get?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez update the code , can you help to get rid of if and else

Comment: why you want to avoid the `if/else` ? also, I'm sure flavian's answer covers almost everything I was thinking in answering too. Is there any other thing, related with this, that you would like us to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List("a", "b1").foldLeft("") { case (acc, el) => acc + el }
```

You're slightly misusing `foldLeft`. The key thing to remember is that you pass in a function that takes an accumulator and the "current element", as well as a seed value, and feeds in the result of the "current" step as the "seed" or accumulator for the next step.

Reading from the top:

- Take my list of List("a", "b1")
- Starting from the empty string `""` as the accumulator
- For every element in the list, call the function against the "current" value of the accumulator.
- In the above case, concatenate the "current" element to the existing accumulator.
- Pass the result to the next step as the seed value.

There's no `+=` like in your example, as you're not mutating the value, instead the return of the "current step", will be the initial accumulator value for the next step, it's all immutable.

In effect:
 - Step 0: `acc = ""`, `el = "a"`, so you get `"" + "a" = "a"`(this is the value of acc at the next stage)
 - Step 1: `acc = "a"`, `el = "b1"`, so you get `"a" + "b1" = "ab1"`

It's also worth nothing that the empty string `""` is a the zero element for string concatenation, so there's no value in checking for empty.

For your specific example:

```
List("a", "b1").foldLeft("") { case (acc, el) =>
  if (el.isEmpty) acc else acc + "abc" + el
}
```

**In your case, collect is probably better**

```
l.collect {
  case s if s.nonEmpty =>  "abc" + s
} mkString ";"
```

Comment: what is wrong in taking a List as compared to "" as accumulator

Comment: @coder25 It's dirty and confusing, if you're using `foldLeft` to go from `List[A]` to `List[B]` you should probably `map` or `collect` instead, just like in this example.

Comment: @flavian great answer, I was going to point out too that using a `map` would be better, but I thought coder25 was learning scala so there is nothing wrong with doing this in terms of `foldLeft`. Anyways `map` can be implemented using foldLeft only.

Comment: @flavian can you explain how collect will be better than foldleft

Comment: I really don't think it being "dirty" is a good answer. I hate side effects as much as the next person, but string concatenation is _really slow_. Creating a buffer is OK when the scope is limited.

Comment: @erip I don't think the OPs question had anything at all to do with performance.

Comment: @coder25 Look at the example at the bottom of my code, no point using `foldLeft` when  using `map` or `collect` is a lot simpler and a one liner.

Comment: @flavian I also don't think OPs question had to do with cleanliness. I don't see your point.